# Django project database

Tags: django, database, sqlite

i have created a project using Django . how can i view stored data in database of my project ?
i have tried below command in cmd

```
>***python manage.py dbshell***
***sqlite>** *.tables*

auth_group                  django_admin_log
auth_group_permissions      django_content_type
auth_permission             django_migrations
auth_user                   django_session
auth_user_groups            poll_poll
auth_user_user_permissions

**sqlite>** *.header on*
**sqlite>** *.mode column*
**sqlite>** *pragma table_info('auth_user');*


 cid         name        type        notnull     dflt_value  pk
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           id          integer     1                       1
1           password    varchar(12  1                       0
2           last_login  datetime    0                       0
3           is_superus  bool        1                       0
4           username    varchar(15  1                       0
5           first_name  varchar(30  1                       0
6           email       varchar(25  1                       0
7           is_staff    bool        1                       0
8           is_active   bool        1                       0
9           date_joine  datetime    1                       0
10          last_name   varchar(15  1                       0
```

it is giving above info but i am not able to view actual data stored by users in database
how to view that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just view your model data...you can view it all accessing the Django built-in admin interface.

1. Register your model in admin.py

```
    from .models import your_model_name

    admin.site.register(your_model_name)
```

Make sure you make migrations!!!!!!

```
    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate
```

2. Create a superuser from command-line

```
    python manage.py createsuperuser
```

3. Run server and go to /admin and enter your credentials you just created. You can see your model name and in that your objects containing data.